# How could I use css to position an element over multiple divs and have one resize height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a website that has quite a convoluted layout. The issue is that there are two divs that are completely circular but then cut off to fit the screen. I want the content to overlay those 2 divs, however, if it gets higher than those two divs there should be space added between those two divs so the content doesn't slip off the last (second) div.

An example is here: https://codepen.io/erce312/pen/YzaKVJM (Note I used tailwind)

```
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-transparent relative overflow-hidden">
  <div class="overflow-hidden absolute" style="background-color: rgb(115, 108, 64); width: 1312.5px; height: 1312.5px; top: 0px; bottom: unset; right: unset; left: 0px; z-index: 0; border-top-left-radius: 9999px; border-top-right-radius: 9999px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-1 flex flex-col h-full items-center bg-purple-500">
  <div class="bg-green-200 my-10 flex flex-1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
      tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
      felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
      tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
      est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
      tellus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-200 my-10 flex flex-1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
      tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
      felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
      tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
      est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
      tellus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-200 my-10 flex flex-1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
      tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
      felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
      tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
      est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
      tellus.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-green-200 my-10 flex flex-1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
      tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
      felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
      tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
      est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
      tellus.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-transparent relative overflow-hidden">
  <div class="overflow-hidden absolute" style="background-color: rgb(115, 108, 64); width: 1312.5px; height: 1312.5px; top: unset; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: unset; z-index: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 9999px; border-bottom-right-radius: 9999px;"></div>
</div>
```

To explain it on the example:
The two green circular divs are fine the way they are. The mint-colored cards should be positioned so that they start at the top of the first green circular div and reach the end of the bottom one. Upon resizing the middle, the purple-colored div should change its height to make sure the content is still from the top of the 1st green div to the bottom of the 2nd one.

The only way I could do this resizing of the middle div is using js, but I don't want to if it's not necessary.

[image: layout]

Edit:

I have pretty much what I want here except the height of the main div should be coming from the flexbox not the style.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/erce312/pen/YzaKVJM

```
<div class="h-full flex flex-col items-center relative" style="height: 3000px">
  <div class="z-10 w-screen h-screen bg-transparent relative overflow-hidden">
    <div class="overflow-hidden absolute" style="background-color: rgb(115, 108, 64); width: 1312.5px; height: 1312.5px; top: 0px; bottom: unset; right: unset; left: 0px; z-index: 0; border-top-left-radius: 9999px; border-top-right-radius: 9999px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col h-full items-center absolute bg-purple-500">
    <div class="bg-green-200 m-10 flex flex-1 z-20">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 m-10 flex flex-1 z-20">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 m-10 flex flex-1 z-20">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 m-10 flex flex-1 z-20">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
        tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
        felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
        tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
        est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
        tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
      <div class="bg-green-200 m-10 flex flex-1 z-20">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
      tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
      felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
      tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
      est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
      tellus.
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae
      tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum
      felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor
      tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum at, feugiat id
      est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper
      tellus.
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-screen z-10 h-screen bg-transparent absolute bottom-0 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="overflow-hidden absolute" style="background-color: rgb(115, 108, 64); width: 1312.5px; height: 1312.5px; top: unset; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: unset; z-index: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 9999px; border-bottom-right-radius: 9999px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add (draw) layout image how it should look like?

Comment: @Anton here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t27oE2rEjrQEFJUAfIlVOAeeJb8dlDZI/view?usp=sharing hope its clear enough

Comment: Remember that CSS [has variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) that you can use to size things relative to your viewport, and can be used in `calc()` statements to set derivative dimensions on pretty much anything you need, so they just "do the right thing(tm)" on resize. Don't forget about "plain CSS" just because you're using tailwind =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution with grid on the parent (body) node and additional wrapper inside the center div. The wrapper needs us to stretch our content to full height. With extra plain CSS we calculate and increase our center div element.

#### style.css

```css
body {
  --initial-size: 500px;
  --start-grow: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:
    1fr
    minmax(calc(var(--initial-size) + (var(--start-grow) - 100vw)), var(--initial-size))
    1fr;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```css
body {
  --initial-size: 500px;
  --start-grow: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:
  1fr 
  minmax(calc(var(--initial-size) + (var(--start-grow) - 100vw)), var(--initial-size)) 
  1fr;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-transparent relative overflow-hidden background-top">
  <div class="overflow-hidden absolute" style="
          background-color: rgb(115, 108, 64);
          width: 1312.5px;
          height: 1312.5px;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          z-index: 0;
          border-top-left-radius: 9999px;
          border-top-right-radius: 9999px;
        "></div>
</div>
<div class="flex-1 flex flex-col h-full items-center bg-purple-500 background-center">
  <main class="flex flex-col justify-between absolute inset-0 z-10">

    <div class="bg-green-200 flex py-8">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum
        at, feugiat id est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 flex py-8">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum
        at, feugiat id est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 flex py-8">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum
        at, feugiat id est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 flex py-8">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum
        at, feugiat id est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-green-200 flex py-8">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae tempor sem. Morbi tempus ut lacus ac porttitor. Nunc eu condimentum felis, et sollicitudin metus. Morbi et nunc quam. Quisque tempor tellus dolor. Etiam nunc lectus, pulvinar eu bibendum
        at, feugiat id est. Morbi et sem pharetra, consequat ligula imperdiet, semper tellus.
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
</main>
</div>
<div class="w-screen h-screen bg-transparent relative overflow-hidden background-bottom">
  <div class="overflow-hidden absolute" style="
          background-color: rgb(115, 108, 64);
          width: 1312.5px;
          height: 1312.5px;
          bottom: 0px;
          right: 0px;
          z-index: 0;
          border-bottom-left-radius: 9999px;
          border-bottom-right-radius: 9999px;
        "></div>
</div>
```